# $\Sigma_1$ is Henkin theorie why is $\Sigma_2 \supset \Sigma_1$ also a Henkin theorie

Tags: logic

I read in my lecture notes that if $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2$ are theories in the same Language such that $\Sigma_1 \subset \Sigma_2$ and $\Sigma_1$ is Henkin then also $\Sigma_2$ is Henkin.

Unfortunately there is no proof and I don't have any idea how to show this, because it seems to be not true to me. However, since this result will be used later I guess it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the definition of a Henkin theory:

> $T$ is Henkin if for every formula $\varphi(x)$ in the language, there is some constant symbol $c$ such that $T$ proves $\exists x\varphi(x)\implies\varphi(c)$.

(There are a few alternate ways to phrase this; they all basically come out to the same thing though.)

Now fix some formula $\varphi(x)$ in the language of $\Sigma_2$.

- Since $\Sigma_2$ is in the same language as $\Sigma_1$, every formula $\varphi(x)$ in the language of $\Sigma_2$ is also in the language of $\Sigma_1$.
- Since $\Sigma_1$ is Henkin, $\Sigma_1$ proves $$(*)\quad\exists x\varphi(x)\implies \varphi(c)$$ for some constant symbol $c$.
- Now does $\Sigma_2$ prove $(*)$? *HINT: think about the relationship between $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ . . .*

Since this works for any $\varphi$, we have that $\Sigma_2$ is Henkin.

---

Note that it is crucial that $\Sigma_2$ be *in the same language* as $\Sigma_1$ - in order to apply the Henkinness of $\Sigma_1$ in the argument above, we needed to "pull down" $\varphi$ to the $\Sigma_1$ context.

Comment: Apparently I got the definition of Henkin wrong.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek What definition did you have for Henkin? (Different texts sometimes use definitions - I just want to double-check that I didn't miss a subtlety.)

Comment: Basically the same I just interpreted that it only counts if $\exists x \phi(x) \in \Sigma$. Now it turned out that this condition isn't necessary.
I think you also have a typo in your definition: at the end there should be $\phi(c)$

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Yup, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi$ be a formula in $L$ with one free variable. Then for some $c\in L$, $\exists x\Phi(x) \implies \Phi(c)$ is in $\Sigma_1$, so it is in $\Sigma_2$. This is for any formula $\Phi$ so $\Sigma_2$ is Henkin.